# django unique_for atributes in models

Tags: django, django-models

In the past, I think there was a model atrtibute named unique_for to define a foreignKey but I can't find it anymore.
Suppose a model named `Recommendation`. A User can recommend many websites but only one by domain. So, I wanted to set a `unique_for('user', 'recommendation.domain')` or something like like this.
What's the current way to do it ?

Recommendation Model:

```
class Recommendation(models.Model):
    is_recommended = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    what = models.ForeignKey('Website', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    who = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    why = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    when = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-when"]
```

User Model is the Django built in.
Thanks

Comment: Please share your models of `User` and `Recommendation` here to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I've found my answser.
The attribute is [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together) and not unique_for